# How to write a MySql select query where id NOT IN list, that can be empty

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, where-in

I have a use case to select ids from table where name should not be in a list that is generated dynamically and can be empty sometimes

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT id FROM APP_TABLE a WHERE a.app_id = :appId AND a.name NOT IN (<nameList>)")
public List<Long> getIds(@Bind("appId") String appId, @BindIn(value = "nameList") List<String> nameList);
```

An exception is thrown whenever the nameList is empty. please suggest to modify the query to achieve that use case.

Comment: If `<nameList>` is from another query a `SELECT id FROM APP_TABLE a LEFT JOIN othertable ON a.name = othertable.name {..other critiera} WHERE othertable.name IS NULL` would be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Just add blank in the list if it's empty,
`if(nameList.isEmpty())
         nameList.add("");`